# ReactJS: Logged in with Google, but callback not coming to application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-signin

I get the right scripts in my `index.html`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function triggerGoogleLoaded() {
        console.log("google event loaded");
        //window.dispatchEvent(new Event('google-loaded'));
    }
</script>
```

and I have `LoginButton` component which does most of the work and it looks like

```
/* global gapi */
import React from 'react';


class LoginButton extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.onSignIn = this.onSignIn.bind(this);
    }


    onSignIn(googleUser) {
        console.log("user signed in"); // plus any other logic here
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        gapi.load('auth2', () => {
            // Retrieve the singleton for the GoogleAuth library and set up the client.
            this.auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
                client_id: '793065510867-j06sr2rufh7ns1kepcdolt9l22ph5pso.apps.googleusercontent.com'
            });

         });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="g-signin2" data-onsuccess={this.onSignIn}></div>
        );
    }

}

export default LoginButton;
```

When I start my application as `yarn start`, I am able to do the following

- A google sign in button appears
- On click, Google asks me to login with my existing account

**Expected**
- `onSignIn` should be executed and I should be able to see `user signed in`

**Actual**

- No console message is logged, this makes me believe that `onSignIn` is not called.

I am not sure how to further debug this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

The entire codebase is available at https://github.com/hhimanshu/google-login-with-react

**UPDATE**
The app is running on http://localhost:3000 and the same is provided in *Authorized JavaScript origins* in Google Developer Console.

Comment: What makes `data-onsuccess` the prop function that is called on success? Also you cannot have dashes in your JSX prop definitions.

Comment: @jakeed1, I do not know about your first question. What do you mean by `dashes` ?

Comment: i thought you were trying to define `data-onsuccess` as a prop function, but i see thats part of the google auth api library... see answer below (worked for me)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class LoginButton extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  onSignIn(googleUser) {
    console.log("user signed in..", googleUser); // plus any other logic here
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    gapi.load('auth2', () => {
      var auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
        client_id: your_id,
        fetch_basic_profile: false,
        scope: 'profile'
      });
      auth2.signIn().then(googleUser => {
        this.onSignIn(googleUser);
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="g-signin2" data-onsuccess={() => this.onSignIn}></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This will both try to sign in on mount, and if not already logged in, allow you to click the button for login.

Inspired by the source code [here](https://github.com/kennetpostigo/react-google-login-component)

Answer (score 0):

In readable way you can do this :

```
const gapiLoaded = () => new Promise((resolve) => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (window.gapi != null) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      resolve();
    }
  }, 100);
});

await gapiLoaded();

console.log("Cool gapi is now defined");
```